# How format data object in Javascript or VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to build small application in `VueJs` where I'm receiving data in following format:

```
{
    "interactions":[
        {
            "id":14,
            "user_id":1,
            "schedule":"2017-06-04 05:02:12",
            "type":"Meeting",
            "with_client":0,
            "event_type":"2",
            "venue":"Mumbai",
            "created_at":"2017-06-04 07:15:37",
            "updated_at":"2017-06-04 07:15:37",
            "deleted_at":null,
            "meeting":{
                "id":14,
                "user_id":1,
                "schedule":"2017-06-04 05:02:12",
                "type":"Meeting",
                "with_client":0,
                "event_type":"2",
                "venue":"Mumbai",
                "created_at":"2017-06-04 07:15:37",
                "updated_at":"2017-06-04 07:15:37",
                "deleted_at":null,
                "clients_association":[
                    {
                        "id":4,
                        "company_id":8,
                        "salutation":"Mr",
                        "first_name":"Check 2",
                        "last_name":"Contact",
                        "number":"098765",
                        "email":"check2@contact.com",
                        "alt_email":null,
                        "address":null,
                        "city":null,
                        "state":null,
                        "country":null,
                        "profile":"Investor-Senior",
                        "sectors_interested":"[\"Financial Services\",\"Metals & Mining\",\"Real Estate\",\"Cement\"]",
                        "companies_interested":"[9]",
                        "created_at":"2017-06-03 06:29:38",
                        "updated_at":"2017-06-03 06:29:38",
                        "deleted_at":null,
                        "pivot":{
                            "interaction_id":14,
                            "contact_id":4
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id":5,
                        "company_id":9,
                        "salutation":"Ms",
                        "first_name":"Ammy",
                        "last_name":"Contact",
                        "number":null,
                        "email":"ammy@contact.com",
                        "alt_email":null,
                        "address":null,
                        "city":null,
                        "state":null,
                        "country":null,
                        "profile":"Company-Promoter",
                        "sectors_interested":"[\"Pharmaceuticals\",\"Infrastructure\",\"Metals & Mining\",\"Auto\",\"Auto Ancillaries\",\"Real Estate\",\"Telecoms\",\"Capital Goods\"]",
                        "companies_interested":"[7]",
                        "created_at":"2017-06-03 06:30:50",
                        "updated_at":"2017-06-03 06:30:50",
                        "deleted_at":null,
                        "pivot":{
                            "interaction_id":14,
                            "contact_id":5
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "contacts_association":[
                    {
                        "id":2,
                        "company_id":5,
                        "salutation":"Mr",
                        "first_name":"Check",
                        "last_name":"Contact",
                        "number":"234567890",
                        "email":"check@contact.com",
                        "alt_email":null,
                        "address":"Thane",
                        "city":"Thane",
                        "state":"Maharastra",
                        "country":"India",
                        "profile":"Research-Corporate Access",
                        "sectors_interested":"[\"Infrastructure\",\"Financial Services\",\"Capital Goods\",\"Pharmaceuticals\",\"Real Estate\"]",
                        "companies_interested":"[7]",
                        "created_at":"2017-06-02 19:32:30",
                        "updated_at":"2017-06-02 19:32:30",
                        "deleted_at":null,
                        "pivot":{
                            "interaction_id":14,
                            "contact_id":2
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id":3,
                        "company_id":4,
                        "salutation":"Mr",
                        "first_name":"Check 1",
                        "last_name":"Contact",
                        "number":null,
                        "email":"check1@contact.com",
                        "alt_email":null,
                        "address":null,
                        "city":null,
                        "state":null,
                        "country":null,
                        "profile":"Investor-Research Head",
                        "sectors_interested":"[\"Economics\",\"Real Estate\",\"Auto\",\"Consumer\",\"Logistics\",\"Oil & Gas\",\"Industrial\",\"Capital Goods\"]",
                        "companies_interested":"[8]",
                        "created_at":"2017-06-03 06:28:03",
                        "updated_at":"2017-06-03 06:28:03",
                        "deleted_at":null,
                        "pivot":{
                            "interaction_id":14,
                            "contact_id":3
                        }
                    },

                ],
                "stellar_participants":[
                    {
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"Analyst",
                        "email":"analyst@example.com",
                        "address":null,
                        "city":null,
                        "state":null,
                        "country":null,
                        "role":"Analyst",
                        "supervisor_id":null,
                        "created_at":null,
                        "updated_at":null,
                        "deleted_at":null,
                        "pivot":{
                            "interaction_id":14,
                            "user_id":1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

There are lot more information which is being received I want to have it in a format something like this:

```
forEach(client_association)
{
    if(this.client_name == null)
    {
        this.client_name = client_association.first_name+ ' '+client.assciation.last_name
    }
    else
    {
        this.client_name = this.client_name + ', ' + client_association.first_name+ ' '+client_association.last_name
    }
}
forEach(stellar_participants)
{
    if(this.stellar_participants_name == null)
    {
        this.stellar_participants_name = stellar_participants.name
    }
    else
    {
        this.stellar_participants_name = this.stellar_participants_name + ', ' + stellar_participants.name
    }
}
forEach(contacts_participants)
{
    if(this.contacts_participants_name == null)
    {
        this.contacts_participants_name = contacts_participants.first_name + ' ' + contacts_participants.last_name
    }
    else
    {
        this.contacts_participants_name = contacts_participants.first_name + ' ' + contacts_participants.last_name
    }
}
```

So my final format will be:

```
meeting_date = 2017-06-04 05:02:12 //Schedule
meeting_call = Meeting //type
event_type = 2 //event_type
venue = Mumbai //venue
with_client = 0
stellar_participants = Analyst //stellarParticipants
clients_association = Check 2 Contact, Ammy Contact //adding all the names in clients association
contacts_association = Check Contact, Check 1 Contact //adding all the names in contacts association
```

so that it takes it into one variable and it gets easier while filtering the data. Please guide me how to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you need. Instead of your code can you show the desired final data object based on your received data? Looks like it's unrelated to Vue and has more in common with JS data filtering.

Comment: @wostex I've updated the question, please review.

Comment: which parts do you want to have in one object?

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm getting array element so for each element I want to have  information `meeting_date`, `meeting_call`, `event_type`, `venue`, `with_client` now `stellar_participants` is also an array so I want to merge the array with one object which holds all the name of those object separated by comma same thing with `clients_association` and `contacts_association` but client and contacts have `first_name` and `last_name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution: just straightforward `map` through your data. This code creates an array where each element is an object representing one element in `interactions` array:

```js
var a = {
    "interactions":[
        {
            "id":14,
            "user_id":1,
            "schedule":"2017-06-04 05:02:12",
            "type":"Meeting",
            "with_client":0,
            "event_type":"2",
            "venue":"Mumbai",
            "created_at":"2017-06-04 07:15:37",
            "updated_at":"2017-06-04 07:15:37",
            "deleted_at":null,
            "meeting":{
                "id":14,
                "user_id":1,
                "schedule":"2017-06-04 05:02:12",
                "type":"Meeting",
                "with_client":0,
                "event_type":"2",
                "venue":"Mumbai",
                "created_at":"2017-06-04 07:15:37",
                "updated_at":"2017-06-04 07:15:37",
                "deleted_at":null,
                "clients_association":[
                    {
                        "id":4,
                        "company_id":8,
                        "salutation":"Mr",
                        "first_name":"Check 2",
                        "last_name":"Contact",
                        "number":"098765",
                        "email":"check2@contact.com",
                        "alt_email":null,
                        "address":null,
                        "city":null,
                        "state":null,
                        "country":null,
                        "profile":"Investor-Senior",
                        "sectors_interested":"[\"Financial Services\",\"Metals & Mining\",\"Real Estate\",\"Cement\"]",
                        "companies_interested":"[9]",
                        "created_at":"2017-06-03 06:29:38",
                        "updated_at":"2017-06-03 06:29:38",
                        "deleted_at":null,
                        "pivot":{
                            "interaction_id":14,
                            "contact_id":4
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id":5,
                        "company_id":9,
                        "salutation":"Ms",
                        "first_name":"Ammy",
                        "last_name":"Contact",
                        "number":null,
                        "email":"ammy@contact.com",
                        "alt_email":null,
                        "address":null,
                        "city":null,
                        "state":null,
                        "country":null,
                        "profile":"Company-Promoter",
                        "sectors_interested":"[\"Pharmaceuticals\",\"Infrastructure\",\"Metals & Mining\",\"Auto\",\"Auto Ancillaries\",\"Real Estate\",\"Telecoms\",\"Capital Goods\"]",
                        "companies_interested":"[7]",
                        "created_at":"2017-06-03 06:30:50",
                        "updated_at":"2017-06-03 06:30:50",
                        "deleted_at":null,
                        "pivot":{
                            "interaction_id":14,
                            "contact_id":5
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "contacts_association":[
                    {
                        "id":2,
                        "company_id":5,
                        "salutation":"Mr",
                        "first_name":"Check",
                        "last_name":"Contact",
                        "number":"234567890",
                        "email":"check@contact.com",
                        "alt_email":null,
                        "address":"Thane",
                        "city":"Thane",
                        "state":"Maharastra",
                        "country":"India",
                        "profile":"Research-Corporate Access",
                        "sectors_interested":"[\"Infrastructure\",\"Financial Services\",\"Capital Goods\",\"Pharmaceuticals\",\"Real Estate\"]",
                        "companies_interested":"[7]",
                        "created_at":"2017-06-02 19:32:30",
                        "updated_at":"2017-06-02 19:32:30",
                        "deleted_at":null,
                        "pivot":{
                            "interaction_id":14,
                            "contact_id":2
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id":3,
                        "company_id":4,
                        "salutation":"Mr",
                        "first_name":"Check 1",
                        "last_name":"Contact",
                        "number":null,
                        "email":"check1@contact.com",
                        "alt_email":null,
                        "address":null,
                        "city":null,
                        "state":null,
                        "country":null,
                        "profile":"Investor-Research Head",
                        "sectors_interested":"[\"Economics\",\"Real Estate\",\"Auto\",\"Consumer\",\"Logistics\",\"Oil & Gas\",\"Industrial\",\"Capital Goods\"]",
                        "companies_interested":"[8]",
                        "created_at":"2017-06-03 06:28:03",
                        "updated_at":"2017-06-03 06:28:03",
                        "deleted_at":null,
                        "pivot":{
                            "interaction_id":14,
                            "contact_id":3
                        }
                    },

                ],
                "stellar_participants":[
                    {
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"Analyst",
                        "email":"analyst@example.com",
                        "address":null,
                        "city":null,
                        "state":null,
                        "country":null,
                        "role":"Analyst",
                        "supervisor_id":null,
                        "created_at":null,
                        "updated_at":null,
                        "deleted_at":null,
                        "pivot":{
                            "interaction_id":14,
                            "user_id":1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
    ]
};

var res = a.interactions.map(i => Object.assign({
  'meeting_date': i.schedule,
  'meeting_call': i.type,
  'event_type': i.event_type,
  'venue': i.venue,
  'with_client': i.with_client
  }, {
   'stellar_participants': i.meeting.stellar_participants.map(sp => sp.name).join(', ')
  }, {
   'clients_association': i.meeting.clients_association.map(ca => ca.first_name + ' ' + ca.last_name).join(', ')
  }, {
   'contacts_association': i.meeting.contacts_association.map(ca => ca.first_name + ' ' + ca.last_name).join(', ')
  }));

console.log(res)
```